# Is there away to store info, without a database?

Tags: c#, .net, database, saving-data

HI, I was wondering is there any way to store data, like say I wanted to make a login form and save the usernames and passwords, without using a database or .txt file? Seems like alot of work to set up stuff like that, for something simple, and I was just wondering if there was another way. :)

And if any one has some tutorials on how to use a database Access/Sql/Local Database please post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me this is a job for [Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You have to put it somewhere to persist it, and I'm not sure how a text file is "a lot of work", especially when compared to a database.  Since you used the c# tag, I guess you could put it in the registry if you want, which doesn't require making any new files on the disk.

Comment: Well I mean a .txt file isn't alot of work but some one could just open it and read it, and I wouldn't want to create a .txt file for every user that is created.

Comment: after recently spending several hours cleaning the registry from a botched McAfee enterprise installation i would strongly suggest against using the registry ;-)

Comment: @Anders - yeah, I misread the original question as saving the state of  an application, like the last username used to login on a form.  Putting an entire database of users in the registry would be insanity.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment to JC, it sounds like you're talking about persistence, which is the idea of saving the state of an object for a latter run. (Mentioning logins threw everyone off, I think).  I'm not much of a C# hacker, but some quick googling turned up [this](http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/2222431/Building-Persistence-into-NET-Programs.htm).

It sounded like you might be looking for application settings specifically, tutorial [here](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33944).

Answer (score 1):

Databases are way better than text files, especially when you're well-organized.  For example, having a database table with Username and Password columns [ie:

```
 +------------+------------+
 + Username   + Password   +
 +------------+------------+
 + Blargh     + Badajaja   +
 + Trinkle    + GALUMPADA  +
 +-------------------------+
```

is much more legible than
`6Blargh8Badajaja7Trinkle9GALUMPADA`
or
`Blargh^]Badajaja^]Trinkle^]GALUMPADA`

MySQL is easy to work with using C#, just use google to find a ton of guides/tutorials.

Comment: You **MUST NOT** store passwords in plain text.

Comment: ... especially if your password is "Dinkle". Nobody wants to read that.

Comment: You know I actually didn't know that "dinkle" meant... erm.  It sounds cool when next to trinkle.  Anyways, time to change where I live on facebook.  It was set to Trinkledinkle, heh...  Oh, and @SLaks, I can write up an implementation of ROT13 for you easily.  Don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scale, I would use a database.  A really large text file can be expensive to read in all the time, and I just personally like using databases more for situations like this.

Here's a link to a tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257(VS.80).aspx

Security wise, both will work, you can encrypt both, however being able to encrypt/decrypt row by row without a whole bunch of extra code is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing. Sounds almost like you're asking how to save the data without saving the data.

Maybe you're just not wanting to use a full RDBMS like SQL Server or Oracle or even SQL Server Express? Then there's [SQL Lite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

Comment: OK, maybe I should put it this way, is there a way to store a variables value? Like if this windows should run on start-up of the program or not to run. You know what I mean so it can remember stuff like that or what color background you had chosen for the app, and different stuff like that